# Seeing the difference/losing information when comparing different formats

Tags: gimp, file-format, comparison

You can hear the resulting loss of sound information when you invert an mp3 in an audio tool and mix and render it together with the wav format. You can now hear the difference between the mp3 and the wav.

I try to do the same with image file formats, jpg and tiff.

How do I achieve this with the program "GIMP"?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with photography, but have a look at ImageMagicks "compare" utility. Alternately, if GIMP is a requirement, load up both images on separate layers, and subtract one from the other.

Comment: Keep in mind that whether you are looking at a jpeg or a tiff, the image actually displayed on your screen will be displayed more or less at uncompressed jpeg quality. If you are using a 16-bit tiff the viewing application itself will convert it to 8-bits so that it can be displayed within the limits of your monitor's capabilities.

Comment: @twalberg Can you explain me in a little more detail how to substract one from the other? Thanks too to Michael Clark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With Gimp

- `File>Open` the TIFF file
- `File>Open as layers` the JPEG file
- Set the mode of the JPEG layer to `Difference` (Mode selector at the top of the Layers list, which by default says `Normal`).
- If you want explore the difference a bit more, `Layer>new from visible` will create a layer with that difference.
- You can then use the `Levels` or `Threshold` tool on that new layer to increase the difference and make it more visible.